# How to compress with the default name in 7z?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, 7zip

I have a variable named file called `fooDATE.txt` when `DATE` is the variable part.

> How to compress this file using command line (in Windows with 7z) so that the compressed file has the **same** name as the original file?
>   I want it to be called in the same way as the source file.

For example:
For the file `foo20170302.txt` compress to `foo20170302.zip`

This not work:
`7z.exe -tzip C:\foo*.zip C:\foo*.txt`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In directory where files are present use dos for loop with [substitution modifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true). Your case as follows:

`for %f in (*.txt) do 7z.exe -tzip "%~nf.zip" "%~nf.txt"`

Comment: Your answer was helpful. **Partly**.
My problem is that 7z.exe is contained in a different folder, and this can't be otherwise.
What would be the sentence in this case? Thank you very much again.